# Conditionally add class to a webform component

Tags: webforms

I have a webform with a few "formula" components performing simple math calculations using the [webform calculator](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_calculator) module.

I am trying to theme the output of the webform in order to add a class to the formula component, depending on the value of the component being calculated.

In my webform-form-[formid]-tpl.php, I have something like this.

```
 <?php
if ($form['submitted']['mycomponent']['#value']==0) { ?>
    <span class="green"><?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['subtotal']); ?></span><?php
}

else { ?>
    <span class="red"><?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['subtotal']); ?><?php
} ?>
?>
```

which obviously doesn't work, since I probably miss the whole point :)

Any clue about what can I do in order to accomplish that?

Thanks.